# AttributeError: 'ClientCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'invoke_endpoint'

Tags: async-await, boto3, python-asyncio, boto

I am trying to use the aioboto3 library to invoke an endpoint on SageMaker asynchronously.
Below is the simple python code for that

```
import asyncio

import aioboto3


async def entry():
    sagemaker_client = aioboto3.session.Session(profile_name='mlbeta').client('sagemaker-runtime')

    request_body = "...<some-payload>..."

    response = await sagemaker_client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName='ASMSummaryGenerator',
        Body=request_body,
        ContentType='application/json'
    )

    response_json = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

    print(response_json)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(entry())
```

I get the following error when I run this code

```
/Users/rppatwa/anaconda3/bin/python /Volumes/Unix/workplace/RPPythonTestsWS/src/RPPythonTests/src/PythonPlayground/AsyncBoto3SpeakableTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Unix/workplace/RPPythonTestsWS/src/RPPythonTests/src/PythonPlayground/AsyncBoto3SpeakableTest.py", line 43, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(entry())
  File "/Users/rppatwa/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Volumes/Unix/workplace/RPPythonTestsWS/src/RPPythonTests/src/PythonPlayground/AsyncBoto3SpeakableTest.py", line 30, in entry
    response = await sagemaker_client.invoke_endpoint(
AttributeError: 'ClientCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'invoke_endpoint'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AioSession._create_client' was never awaited
```

Does the aioboto3 library support awaiting the invoke_endpoint() api? If not, how can achieve the asynchronous execution through some other means. Appreciate your response. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Judging by the error message, you should be awaiting the result of `client()`, e.g. `client = await aioboto3.session.Session(profile_name='mlbeta').client('sagemaker-runtime')`. Additionally, you might need to use `async with` to ensure proper release, something like `async with aioboto3.session.Session(...).client(...) as client: <your code>`